# Designing the home audio setup with musical instruments in mind

Tags: guitar, drums, instruments, homerecording, jamming

I'm trying to plan my new living room from the audio point of view and because it's a small living room, I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use my musical instruments for jamming with friends on the same audio setup as the TV.

On the movie side of things, I plan buying the following:

- a sound bar (Sony HT-Z9F or other) with two wireless rear speakers
- possibly an AV receiver where I can also plug in the vinyl player in addition to the TV

On the music side of things, I already own:

- electronic drum set
- two electro-acoustic guitars

Until now, I used them individually, but I would like to use them together so everybody playing hears everybody else.

Is there a way of doing this? If yes, what components do I need between and how would the design/flow look like?

For example, I know that an audio interface like Focusrite Scarlett   is used for recording purposes, but I was wondering if you can use also use that for the jamming part as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need, apart from what you already plan, is a small mixer - say 6 channel for future growth - that will plug directly into the AV amp. The sound quality and volume may be lacking slightly, but unless you live in a detached property, with no neighbours two feet away, that's a bonus (for them).

Electronic drums can go into two channels (nice stereo), guitars into another couple, leaving room for bass or keys later. With a headphone amp/splitter, even if you're right next to neighbours, you could all use cans, and have quiet, private fun. Also consider a 'rehearsal hub'.

Comment: Thanks @Tim let me see if I got it right: The mixer would get the inputs from the instruments and send the output to the AV receiver from the home theater that would send the music we would create to the speakers/soundbar?  In this scenario, would the AV receiver also amplify the guitar signals?
Would a Scarlett Audio Interface work in the same way? One of the outputs of the interface would sent the output to the AV receiver. What would be the difference be between an audio interface and a mixer in this case?

Comment: Not  having a clue what a Scarlett Audio Interface is, haven't a clue! But, yes, the AV is an amp., and as such will amplify all that gets plugged into it, including a mixer.

Comment: I was referring to these little things: https://focusrite.com/scarlett - they look pretty cool and you can record your multiple inputs to your computer with it.

Comment: @DaJackal The Scarlett Interface is primarily a computer interface that is designed as a means of inputting the signal from mics and instruments into your PC after converting the signal to digital.  Then you can add effects with your DAW on your computer.  An audio Mixer as Tim suggested will often allow you to have more control over the sound in real time.  Many small format mixers have built in effects and many digital mixers can also be used as a computer interface for recording purposes.